# How can I make an image appear in the same position on the screen across different resolutions?

Tags: css

I want to make about 5 different images appear in the same location on the screen across different screen locations.

I can't paste the code of the whole site because I am using MYBB Software.
But here is the site: www.AlphaDiscussion.com(Yes I realize the part around the forum looks ugly, I am waiting for it to update the color)

I want these five images to appear right above the logo.

This is the code in the header template  where the five images are:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TtU3OAY.png" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 500px;">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pDzigv1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 630px;">  
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pLIlkK1.gif" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 730px;">    
        <img src=" http://i.imgur.com/KyYZ8m1.png?dateline=1416083133" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; right: 860px;"> 
     <img src=" http://i.imgur.com/iQUavgQ.gif" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; right: 970px;">
```

They are in a comment tag right now so they won't show up. 
I am typing this from a chromebook, but my main computer is a windows laptop.

So How can I do this?

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @OneWay is that it? Do I keep the same like top: and left: as well?

Comment: @Evan, you'll have to do a much better job explaining than simply stating _"same place across resolutions"_.  What does that mean?  Relative to what?  Same number of pixels away from the left, the top, the bottom?  From each other?  **"Same place" is not really going to be the "same place" after the resolution changes.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean those 5 images centered above your logo?

I saw your code and maybe like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TtU3OAY.png">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pDzigv1.png">  
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pLIlkK1.gif">    
        <img src=" http://i.imgur.com/KyYZ8m1.png?dateline=1416083133"> 
        <img src=" http://i.imgur.com/iQUavgQ.gif">
    </div>
    <center><a href="http://alphadiscussion.com/index.php"><img src="http://alphadiscussion.com/images/logo.png" alt="AlphaDiscussion ~ For the Alphas" title="AlphaDiscussion ~ For the Alphas" /></a></center>
    .....
    ...
```

Create new div above logo (above center tag) with width 100%, and put inside images, then with text-align you can align them center as is here, or text-align:right...

Is that what you need?
those 5 images centered above logo, one after another?

Comment: I want them to be in the same place, ON DIFFERENT RESOLUTIONS.         Like I want the images to not be all over the place on different browser sizes